# Guice generic type injection

Tags: java, guice

Lets say I have a generic class as follows:

```
public class Base<T extends Stoppable> {

  protected final Injector injector;
  protected T stoppable;

  public Base(Module... module) {
    injector = Guice.createInjector(module);
    Key<T> key = Key.get(new TypeLiteral<T>() {});  <-- T cannot be used as a key; It is not fully specified.
    stoppable = injector.getInstance(key);
  }
}
```

The instance of type `Stoppable` is binded using `Multibinder`:

```
Multibinder<Stoppable> taskBinder =
    Multibinder.newSetBinder(binder, Stoppable.class);
taskBinder.addBinding().to(MyClass.class);
```

Is it possible to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not possible to achieve this in a way you are trying to.

But you could pass `Class`/`Type` object to `Base`'s constructor and use it to create needed type literal, e.g. (I use `Set` as key since you mentioned multibinder):

```java
public class Base<T extends Stoppable> {

  protected final Injector injector;
  protected T stoppable;

  public Base(Class<T> type, Module... module) {
    injector = Guice.createInjector(module);
    var key = Key.get(com.google.inject.util.Types.setOf(type));
    stoppable = injector.getInstance(key);
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes, I am actually having Set<T> stoppable.  Thank you for your suggestion!